# how can I know if a smart card is inserted?

Tags: c#, smartcard

I need to know if in the smart card reader is present a smart card.
I could not find a simple example to get it in c#. Can someone help me?
Thank you

Comment: Different companies provide different sdk to connect to smart card readers. usually they have the sdk on their websites.

Comment: Sure, but i want only check if a smart card is present, any card.
Thanks.

Comment: Great question. Stupid choice by admin to close it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use lightweight [pcsc-sharp](https://github.com/danm-de/pcsc-sharp) library to query [PC/SC subsystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC/SC) of your operating system. This [code sample](https://github.com/danm-de/pcsc-sharp/blob/master/Examples/CardStatus/Program.cs) may be interesting for you.

Comment: Absolutely perfect, it was what I wanted. Thank you!